# Django form: can't access help_text from Django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Using Django 1.10. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields), it seems that I should be able to access help_text from the template but I can't.

```
class StudentForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['name', 'age']

        help_text = {
            'age': "enter your age in years and months",
        }
```

In the template, the following prints nothing:

```
{%for field in form %}
    {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template is OK. The problem is that the meta option should be [`help_texts`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields), not `help_text`.

```
class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = ['name', 'age']

    help_texts = {
        'age': "enter your age in years and months",
    }
```

Comment: oh man! And I spent all this while trying to figure this out. I'll obviously not get a compile error since it would be treated as another new dict. Thanks @Alasdair!